# How to make a python code for this functionf(n)?

Tags: python

How to make a Python code for a function f(n) which finds all distinct positive integers `{a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_n} >1` such that

```
$((1+(1/a_1))(1+(1/a_2)...(1+(1/a_n)))-(1/(a_1a_2...a_n))$
```

is a positive integer.

Comment: @user1729 this is neither a code writing nor tutorial service. Consider following a formal Python tutorial.

Comment: Can anyone suggest me how to convert mathematical terms on this site?

Comment: This question would probably do better on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty approach:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as cwr

for x,y,z in cwr(range(2, 20), 3):
    num = (x + 1) * (y + 1) * (z + 1) - 1
    denom = x * y * z
    if num % denom == 0:
        print("{},{},{}: {} / {} == {}".format(x, y, z, num, denom, num // denom))
```

which gives

```
2,4,14: 224 / 112 == 2
```

and extending it to four variables gives

```
2,2,2,2: 80 / 16 == 5
```